# Javascript -- How to create connection independent variables

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html, socket.io

I'm working on a simple chatroom for me and a bunch of friends. I've made it using socket.io, nodeJS, HTML5 JavaScript, and CSS. I wanted to add a nickname feature so I know who's who. So far I have this (I know it's messy, once it's working I'll tidy it up):

index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });

    socket.on('name input', function(nme){
        console.log('Login: ' + nme);
        io.emit('name input', nme);
    });

});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

chat.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TheChatWeb || Web Edition 0.0.2</title>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Heebo:900');
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; background: #bcbcbc; }
      form { padding: 10px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%;}
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; border-top-left-radius: 25px; border-bottom-left-radius: 25px; border-right-style: none; margin-right: 0%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: #d9d9d9; border-size: 2%; border-style: solid; border-color: #c1c1c1; border-top-right-radius: 25px; border-bottom-right-radius: 25px; padding: 10px; margin-left: 0%; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 5%; padding: 10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #32CD32; border-radius:20px; background: #d9d9d9; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; border-radius: 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      ul{ position: relative; }
      html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
      }

      /* The Modal (background) */
      .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
      }

      /* Modal Content */
      .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <input placeholder="Enter your nickname here!" id="nameField" autocomplete="off" minlength="3" maxlength="15"/><button id="nameGo">Go!<button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;item-align:center;font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;font-size:180%;">
        TheChatWeb <hr style="margin-left:35%;" color="blue" size="1px" width="30%"> Web Edition 0.0.2
    </div>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input placeholder="Enter your message here!" id="m" autocomplete="off" minlength="2" maxlength="185"/><button>Send</button>
        <div id="char-count"></div>
    </form>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("nameGo");

        // When the page loads, open the modal 
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
        });

        $(function () {
            var uname;

            var socket = io();
                $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
                socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
                $('#m').val('');
                return false;
            });
            socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(uname + ": " + msg));
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            });

            socket.on('user connected', function(notify){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(notify));
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            });

            socket.on('user disconnected', function(notify){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(notify));
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            });

            socket.on('name input', function(nme){
                $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(nme + " joined the chat! Say hi!"));
                uname = nme;
                window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
            });

            btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
            socket.emit('name input', $('#nameField').val());
        }

        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Now, my issue is, that if I run this by using "node index.js" in PowerShell, it works fine, until someone else logs on, then my username changes to theirs too. I'm wondering if there's a way to keep the usernames stored client-side only, rather then sending to everyone like it does now. Any and all help much appriciated, Thanks!

(Yes i am new to this, this is my first NodeJS app, please be kind .)

My index.js with @ChrisG's solution:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var users = {};

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });

    socket.on('name input', function(nme){
        console.log('Login: ' + nme);
        users[socket.id] = { name: nme };
        io.emit('name input', nme);
    });

});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: You can use `socket.id` to get the user's unique socket id. Use that to store each user's name. A very basic way is to declare `var users = {};`, and when they send their name, use `users[socket.id] = { name: nme };` To read back the name, use `users[socket.id].name`

Comment: @ChrisG Hey, thanks. I tried that (all code snippets in the <script> section on chat.html, but it's still doing the same. Is it because I'm using two windows on the same PC? I'm about the try it on my phone as well. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately, what've I done wrong?

Comment: You have to add that code on the server, it's the server which needs to keep track of a bunch of clients. A client can't "see" anything else but itself and the server.

Comment: @ChrisG I just tried that, but now nothing's appearing, no join message, no chat message, nothing. Just the base HTML and CSS. It won't let me post the code here unfortunately, it's too long.

Comment: I can't debug code I can't see. And why is your server.js so long all of a sudden? How much code did you add?

Comment: As in, it's too long to paste here, but I'll add it to the main post.

Comment: Yeah, don't put longer pieces of code in comments... really not what they're for. Anyway, what you have is fine in principle, but you aren't using the stored nickname anywhere. In the server's `chat message` handler, instead of just sending `msg`, try sending `users[socket.id].name + ": " + msg` (and remove `uname + ": "` in the client code, obviously)

Comment: Btw, if you don't need server stuff like "x changed their username to y" or the like, the simplest solution is to do this on the client: `socket.emit('chat message', uname + ": " + $('#m').val());` This way the server simply relays the message with the username already prepended by the client.

Comment: Ok, I did that, and now when I run it, it gives me this error:

`socket.on('chat message', function(users[socket.id].name + ": " + msg){`

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: You were changing the function parameter; I was referring to the `msg` in the `io.emit()` command.

Comment: Okay, thanks @ChrisG

Comment: It works now! Thanks so much! ❤

Comment: Great, you're welcome :)